# Sed command through shell_exec not being executed

Tags: php, html, bash, sed, shell-exec

I want to execute a shell command after clicking on a button inside of a html code, so:

In my html code:

```
<form action=execute.php method="post">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Reset">
</form>
```

execute.php:

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec("sed -i '2,3d' filename.txt");
    //$output = shell_exec("cat filename.txt");
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

    $url = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);   
    echo "<a href='$url'>Back</a>"; 
?>
```

The purpose is to remove all lines of a text file but the very first one.

I think that the php code is being properly executed since if I modify the shell command by a simple cat, it works as expected, but I can't figure out why it does nothing when the command to execute is that `sed` expression.

I've verified that such `sed` command works when executed directly in CLI and I have also discarded any permissions issue since I chmoded "filename.txt" to 777. In fact if change the php code to append some text to the file it also works. For example:

```
$output = shell_exec("echo hi >> filename.txt");
```

After looking for info I realized that what I want can be done directly with php with:

```
file_put_contents("filename.txt", "");
file_put_contents("filename.txt", "First_line_content");
```

But now I'm just curious about why my `sed` command didn't work.

I'm running LAMP in an Ubuntu desktop with following `sed` version:

```
$ sed --version
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sed creates a temp file in the same directory as the file, the script must have write permissions to this directory.

Comment: Indeed: even if the destination file exists, sed still need write perm to the current directory to write a tmp file!